# To clear cache after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have placed codeigniter code for controller login.I want to clear cache after logout.

```
function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        $this->index();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function logout()
{
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->cache->clean();
        $this->index();
}
```

to clear browser cache in controller construct

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

also [check this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

clearstatcache — Clears file status cache. This function caches information about specific filenames, so you only need to call `clearstatcache()` , php inbuilt function.

To clear the browser cached page :

```
header ("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time())." GMT");  
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: i have placed this code in logout fn it displays error   Call to undefined method Login::clearstatcache()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function delete_cache($uri_string=null)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
    $path = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

    $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
            $CI->config->item('index_page').
            $uri_string;

    $cache_path .= md5($uri);

    return unlink($cache_path);
}
```

If not work

Refer these

[Lib](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki)

[manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line of code in your `logout` function:

```
$this->cache->clean();
```

For More info about cache in codeigniter see [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/caching.html).

Comment: It displays Call to a member function clean() on a non-object

Comment: have you load drive of cache ?? $this->load->driver('cache');

Comment: fine but after logout when i click back button the page is displaying

Comment: than you need to write a code there to check the session is active or not..if there is empty session than it should redirect to index page.for example:
if($this->session->userdata('abc')!=""){
//continue
}
else{
redirect('index.php');
}

write this code in to the controller which calls your home page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch array cache_item_id vise so you can just do the following.

```
$wildcard = 'latest';
$all_cache = $this->cache->cache_info();
foreach ($all_cache as $cache_id => $cache) :
   if (strpos($cache_id, $wildcard) !== false) :
      $this->cache->delete($cache_id);
   endif;
endforeach;
```

Or try this

function logout(){

```
         $this->CI =& get_instance();   
         $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
         $this->cache->clean();
         redirect(base_url());
}
```

Comment: i tried the 2nd but after logout when i click back button it is display  the page

Answer (score -1):

Add below script in your code

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```