# Clearing Cache using middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

Can someone help me if I can use middleware for clearing my cache. because I need is to clear my cache for every time I logged out. Thank you.

Comment: Browser cache? Laravel cache?  I searched for "*laravel clear cache logout*" and found answers for both, did those help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37612269, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29740338, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20067026 ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to clear cache in middleware. Instead, you can maybe write an event listener for it. Whenever you're logged out, you basically land on a login page or something similar. So, in the controller which returns the page, you can add an event listner for your "cache clear" business logic.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you sir. I'll try this. Thank you

Comment: Btw sir. Can you share an example for me about this idea. thank you very much